# Hall effect in metals

Tags: condensed-matter

how the Hall resistivity varies with temperature and magnetic field, in case of metals, semiconductors and insulators?. Can anyone suggest me few books or journals to start with. And is the variation of Hall resistivity and Hall coefficient the same with temperature?

Answer (score 1):

The hall coefficient $R_{H}$ is directly related to the carrier density in the system through the equation $R_{H}=-\frac{1}{ne}$ where $n$ is the mobile carrier density (electrons/holes) and $e$ is the electron charge.

Thus, the variation of $R_{H}$ with temperature is governed by the temperature dependence of the carrier density.

For metals, which have no bandgap and already have a lot of mobile carriers at any temperature, the thermally generated carriers are neglibile, thus $n(T)$ is almost a constant. Therefore, $R_{H}(T)$  should be nearly constant.

For undoped semiconductors, at $T=0$, there are no mobile carriers and all carriers are thermally generated. Thus, $n(T)$ is not a constant. In fact, $n(T)\sim e^{-E_{a}/kT}$ where $E_{a}$ is the activation energy (In this case, the bangap). Even for doped semiconductors, $n$ varies significantly with temperature. Thus, $R_{H}(T)$ can be determined using this exponential behavior of carrier density.